# How to deploy two applications on same weblogic server

Tags: weblogic, oracle12c

I have two different java desktop applications working with web services. Now I want to just run these two applications simultaneously on same weblogic server. Although URL can be differ but want to run on same weblogic server.

Comment: Any difficulties to deploy both applications ?

Comment: This is the error i am facing while deploying .ear to weblogic  :-   Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND <2:3> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'module@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element application@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

Comment: can you post the complete error message and the stack trace ?